# why isn't this jsf/ajax code submitting the values?

Tags: html, ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I'm embedding here a simplified version of a code that is not working for me.
What happens here is that there are 2 forms.

The first form contains an ajaxified `<h:commandLink>` (Using `<f:ajax>`)
The second form contains a form with values.

When the `<h:commandLink>` is pressed, the values in the second form are supposed to be submitted.

What happens in practice is that values are retrieved (the getter function is run) but are not submitted (the setter function never runs).

The `<f:ajax>` runs because I can see the listener method running and the second form does get rerendered after clicking the `<h:commandLink>` but, again, the setter functions are never run.

```
<body>
    <h:form prependId="false">
        <h:panelGroup >
            <h:commandLink >
                <f:ajax event="click"
                    execute=":form_with_values_to_update" render=":form_with_values_to_update"
                    listener="#{mrBean.clickListenerAction}" />
                Do something
            </h:commandLink>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>

    <h:panelGroup>
        <h:form id="form_with_values_to_update">
            <fieldset>
                <ui:repeat value="#{mrBean.aMemberOfBean.aListInAMemberOfBean}" var="listItem">
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <h:outputText value="#{listItem.label}" />
                        <h:inputText id="contact_details_input"
                            value="#{listItem.value}" />
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </ui:repeat>
            </fieldset>
        </h:form>
    </h:panelGroup>
</body>
```

P.S - Using MyFaces JSF 2.1

Comment: One question I could not understand why are you not submitting second form ??

Comment: @Sugandha You mean why I use two separate forms?

Comment: nope why not submit second form using js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commandlink/button has to go in the **same** form as where the data of interest is in.

If that's not an option due to some design or business restrictions, then you need a second commandlink/button. First move the original commandlink/button back in the right form, give it an `id` and hide it using CSS `display: none;`.

Then put the second commandlink/button in the other form which does something like

```xml
<h:commandLink onclick="document.getElementById('form_with_values_to_update:linkid').click(); return false;">
    Do something
</h:commandLink>
```